# выборка из sql с помощью чекбокс

Tags: php, mysql

ес таблица bms с столбцом oper_id в которой записаны числа 1,2,3. Как с помошьйю чекпос выбрать все значения, а также только два или один?

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="oper" name="oper" value="1">B
    <input type="checkbox" id="oper" name="oper" value="2">M
    <input type="checkbox" id="oper" name="oper" value="3">S
    <input type="checkbox" id="oper" name="oper" value="">All
  </label>

$oper = filter_var(trim($_POST['oper']));

SELECT oper FROM bms 
  WHERE oper ='$oper' LIMIT $count;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: oper name
1 sda
2 sdad
1 sdas
3 asdas
3 asdad
2 asdasd
3 sdasd
1 dasd
так выглядит таблица. я хочу с помощью 4 чекбоксов выбирать те строки которые будут совпадать с отмеченным или  отмечеными чекбоксами или выбирать все из колонки name не учитывая параметры колонки oper?

Comment: такая выборка не обращает внимание на сами чекбоксы и всегда выберает все, не смотря на отмечение чекбоксы. как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Ну во первых тебе сам checkbox лучше передать массивом через PHP magic post array

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="oper[]" value="1"> Один</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="oper[]" value="2"> Два</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="oper[]" value="3"> Три</label>
```

PHP код тоже теперь надо оптимизировать под массив.

```
<?php
# $_POST['oper'] теперь будет выглядеть вот так.
$_POST['oper'] = ["1","плохо","2","3"];

# Проверяем все $oper на шлак, всё что не цифра будет 0
$oper = array_map(fn($e) => intval($e), $_POST['oper']);

# Фильтр запроса
$where = "";
if (count($oper) > 0) {
    $where .= " AND oper IN (" . join(',', $oper) . ")";
}

# Это тут уже было ))
$count = 1;
$SQL = "SELECT oper FROM bms WHERE 1 $where LIMIT $count";
echo $SQL;
```

Выхлоп

```sql
SELECT oper FROM bms WHERE 1  AND oper IN (1,0,2,3) LIMIT 1
```